# MySQL table doesn' get updated for multiple entries(JSON) but could for a single entry from JSON in Nodejs

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express, async-await

I cannot figure out how to update table from JSON variable using 'for..of' loop.

Used async/await but, no help!

```
for (const item of file) {  //if I remove for loop and use only a single instance 'eg. file[4]' code works correctly.                   
table(item)

console.log(5)
}

async function table(item){    //file holds "data.json"-->        {Index,Roll,Name}
var x=item
var a=x.Index;
var b=x.Roll;
var c=x.Name;
console.log("connected"+a+b+c)
await sql(a,b,c).then(console.log("After await"))
}
console.log("done");
}

async function sql(a,b,c){console.log("got in async");
return new Promise ((resolve, reject) => {resolve(
con.query('insert into CS(s,roll,name) values(?,?,?)',[a,b,c],function        (err, result){
if (err) throw err;

}))
})
}
```

> OUTPUT

```
connected11111abhilashabhilash
got in async
[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
After await
5
connected21112anuraganurag
got in async
After await
5
connected31113abhinavabhinav
got in async
After await
5
connected41114joshjosh
got in async
After await
5
connected51115caustavcaustav
got in async
After await
5
connected61116deepanshudeepanshu
got in async
After await
5
connected71117eraera
got in async
After await
5
connected81118ekanshekansh
got in async
After await
5
connected91119faranfaran
got in async
After await
5
connected101120faisalfaisal
got in async
After await
5
connected111121gauravgaurav
got in async
After await
5
connected121122mananmanan
got in async
After await
5
connected131123nileshnilesh
got in async
After await
5
done
done
done
done
done
done
done
done
done
done
done
done
done
```

Comment: What does all this code do instead? What have you tried to debug these problems?

Comment: Console shows table updated in backend but it is not actually.